# Robot Framework connectivity with database

Tags: python, database, robotframework

connect to database  psycopg2   connectiondetails

```
${count}=    row count     select count(*) from trial;

 log to console   ${count}
```

-----Here m getting result as [(2,)] ,though I want to compare this result with the string as value '2'. How to grab that from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query results are always returned like that; a list with a tuple, or using an option *returnAsDict*

You access the value by indexing, or convert to other format. In your example:

```
# ${count} is [(2,)]
log to console   ${count[0][0]}
```

But if you look to the example of `Row Count` in the [documentation](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/blob/master/doc/DatabaseLibrary.html), you see that they don't use the `count(*)`, so your code should be:

```
 ${count}=    row count     select * from trial;

 log to console   ${count}
```